# Problem in list comprehension output in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the following liste

```
d=[[(1.0,1.1,1223),(2.0,1.1,1224)],[(3.0,1.1,1222),(4.0,1.1,1222)],[(5.0,1.1,1222),(1.0,1.1,1222)]]
```

I want to obtain the following result using list comprehension:

```
[[(1.0, 1.1), (2.0, 1.1)], [(3.0, 1.1), (4.0, 1.1)], [(5.0, 1.1), (1.0, 1.1)]]
```

I have done this

```
g= [d[i][y][:2] for i in range(len(d)) for y in range(len(d[i]))]
```

However, i got this output:

```
[(1.0, 1.1), (2.0, 1.1), (3.0, 1.1), (4.0, 1.1), (5.0, 1.1), (1.0, 1.1)]
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list comprehension, you need to use one that takes into account that your list `d` is nested,

```
g = [[y[:2] for y in x] for x in d]
```

Here the outer list comprehension loops through the inner lists of `d`, and the inner list comprehension loops through the tuples in those inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints out your desired output:

```
l = [[(1.0,1.1,1223),(2.0,1.1,1224)],[(3.0,1.1,1222),(4.0,1.1,1222)],[(5.0,1.1,1222),(1.0,1.1,1222)]]

b = []

times = 0

for a in l:
    b.append([])
    for x in range(2):
        b[times].append((a[x][0],a[x][1]))
        
    times += 1        
            
print(b)
```